# Bought one refurbished 6 new Seagate Ironwolf 4TB drive. Getting errors like DRDY SENSE ERR

Tags: linux, hard-drive

Getting the following errors when connecting it to the PC
Host OS is Debian-based (Proxmox) and the command is `dmesg -Hw`.

I bought a couple other drives at the same time as this one. I swapped the power and SATA cables around and the other drives don't have this issue. Its only with this hdd.

I replaced this and bought another couple of Ironwolfs.
One of them has the same issue. This time it is brand new.
In the past week I have purchased 6 of these disks and 3 have this issue.

Should I return this HDD, or is this issue fixable?

Edit: I Sincerely recommend that no one buy this model from seagate(Ironwolf 4TB ST4000VN008-2DR166)

```
[Jun 2 19:46] ata5: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[  +0.000111] ata5.00: failed to read native max address (err_mask=0x1)
[  +0.000000] ata5.00: HPA support seems broken, skipping HPA handling
[  +0.000002] ata5.00: ATA-8: ST4000VN008, SC60, max UDMA/133
[  +0.000001] ata5.00: 7814037168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32)
[  +0.000096] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[  +0.000100] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST4000VN008      SC60 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[  +0.000128] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  +0.000101] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 7814037168 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[  +0.000011] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  +0.000001] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[  +0.000014] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  +0.059478] ata5.00: READ LOG DMA EXT failed, trying PIO
[  +0.000038] ata5: failed to read log page 10h (errno=-5)
[  +0.000011] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x1 SAct 0x40 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  +0.000004] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[  +0.000003] ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  +0.000006] ata5.00: cmd 60/08:30:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 6 ncq dma 4096 in
                       res 53/04:30:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[  +0.000006] ata5.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[  +0.000003] ata5.00: error: { ABRT }
[  +0.000166] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[  +0.000018] ata5: EH complete
[  +0.015616] ata5: failed to read log page 10h (errno=-5)
[  +0.000011] ata5.00: NCQ disabled due to excessive errors
[  +0.000001] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x1 SAct 0x20000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  +0.000026] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[  +0.000004] ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  +0.000004] ata5.00: cmd 60/08:88:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq dma 4096 in
                       res 53/04:88:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[  +0.000006] ata5.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[  +0.000003] ata5.00: error: { ABRT }
[  +0.000132] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[  +0.000015] ata5: EH complete
[  +0.023872] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  +0.000010] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[  +0.000005] ata5.00: failed command: READ DMA
[  +0.000004] ata5.00: cmd c8/00:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 18 dma 4096 in
                       res 53/04:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[  +0.000006] ata5.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[  +0.000004] ata5.00: error: { ABRT }
[  +0.000173] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[  +0.000017] ata5: EH complete
[  +0.031795] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  +0.000011] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[  +0.000004] ata5.00: failed command: READ DMA
[  +0.000004] ata5.00: cmd c8/00:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 19 dma 4096 in
                       res 53/04:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[  +0.000006] ata5.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[  +0.000003] ata5.00: error: { ABRT }
[  +0.000162] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[  +0.000015] ata5: EH complete
[  +0.031770] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  +0.000010] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[  +0.000005] ata5.00: failed command: READ DMA
[  +0.000004] ata5.00: cmd c8/00:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 20 dma 4096 in
                       res 53/04:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[  +0.000006] ata5.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[  +0.000003] ata5.00: error: { ABRT }
[  +0.000164] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[  +0.000016] ata5: EH complete
[  +0.023807] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  +0.000011] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[  +0.000005] ata5.00: failed command: READ DMA
[  +0.000004] ata5.00: cmd c8/00:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 21 dma 4096 in
                       res 53/04:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[  +0.000006] ata5.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[  +0.000003] ata5.00: error: { ABRT }
[  +0.000175] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[  +0.000016] scsi_io_completion_action: 6 callbacks suppressed
[  +0.000003] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#21 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  +0.000002] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#21 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[  +0.000001] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#21 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[  +0.000001] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#21 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[  +0.000001] print_req_error: 6 callbacks suppressed
[  +0.000001] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  +0.000008] buffer_io_error: 3 callbacks suppressed
[  +0.000001] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[  +0.000012] ata5: EH complete
[  +0.027757] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  +0.000011] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[  +0.000004] ata5.00: failed command: READ DMA
[  +0.000004] ata5.00: cmd c8/00:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 7 dma 4096 in
                       res 53/04:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[  +0.000006] ata5.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[  +0.000003] ata5.00: error: { ABRT }
[  +0.000175] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
[  +0.000017] ata5: EH complete
[  +0.031764] ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  +0.000010] ata5.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[  +0.000005] ata5.00: failed command: READ DMA
[  +0.000004] ata5.00: cmd c8/00:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 tag 22 dma 4096 in
                       res 53/04:08:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[  +0.000006] ata5.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
[  +0.000003] ata5.00: error: { ABRT }
[  +0.000163] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignored)
```

Comment: You should ask for a refund / change for another drive.

Comment: When you say *reimbursed* .. do you mean *refurbished*?  I mean no offense.

Comment: Sorry, I meant refurbished.

Comment: New and errors.  Refurbished and errors.  I'd be looking for a better quality drive.